# How to open more than one ".html" file at a time

Tags: qt, qt-creator, development-environment

I am working in Qt. I have an Icon that has to open ".html". I can directly open the .html file using QUrl but I have a base folder as Doc, it contains some sub folders each folder has its own ".html". I have to open all at a single click(the Icon which I set for). what could be the best way to do

Comment: you may ask more exact question and provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I have to open more than one ".html" file at a same time

Comment: @CodeConfusion feel free to do it. What is the problem?

Comment: @CodeConfusion .. I have a following code for opening a Single .html file vodi classname::open() QString catalogFilePath = QString::fromStdString(Shared->rodRootDir) + QString("/Doc/TileCatalogue/Scatalogu/index.html");
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(catalogFilePath)); This can open only one.html file. I have to open more than one more file at a time . Doc is my base folder, inside the doc folder i have some sub folders each sub folder has one .html file. I have to open all .html file in a single click